# F# Generic List that holds methods as a method parameter... How to write method signature on Abstract Type

Tags: generics, f#

Trying to figure out how to create a method that takes in a list of methods and another parameter.  I have my method that I created in C# that I'm trying to carry over to F#:

```
public interface IValidator
{
    MethodResult Validate(IList<Func<userModel, MethodResult>> validationMethods
      , userModeltoValidate);
}
```

I've tried something like:

```
type public IValidator =
  abstract Validate : IList<(BasicUserModel -> MethodResult<'a>)>, BasicUserModel 
    -> MethodResult<'a>
```

But it doesn't like the syntax even if I surround the parameter signature with parentheses.  The end goal is to have a method that takes in a list of methods and run them by iterating through the list.

```
public MethodResult Validate(IList<Func<BasicUserModel, MethodResult>> validationMethods, 
   BasicUserModel toValidate)
{
   ...
}
```

The looping part I can get easily with F#, it's the method signature syntax for both the abstract type and the type that's implementing the method that's killing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the abstract method declaration, rather than separating the argument types with commas they should be separated by asterisks, as if the method took a tuple:

```
abstract Validate : IList<(BasicUserModel -> MethodResult<'a>)> * BasicUserModel 
                         -> MethodResult<'a>
```

Here are a few other thoughts:

1. Types are public by default, so you can omit the `public` keyword on your type declaration.
2. It would be more idiomatic (and more flexible for callers) to take a `seq<_>` than an `IList<_>`, unless you're likely to need random access rather than looping.
3. I assume it's intentional, but your F# validate method will be generic (since it returns a `MethodResult<'a>` using an undeclared type parameter `'a`).  If you want a non-generic method on a generic type, then add the `'a` parameter to the type declaration: `type IValidator<'a> = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

The F# equivalent of

```
public MethodResult Validate(
   IList<Func<BasicUserModel, MethodResult>> validationMethods, 
   BasicUserModel toValidate) {
   ...
}
```

is

```
member this.Validate
   (validationMethods : IList<(BasicUserModel -> MethodResult)>, 
    toValidate : BasicUserModel) = ...
```

The only difference being the F# version takes an `IList` of `FSharpFunc` (which is more idiomatic) vs `Func` in C#.